# Como ler um arquivo JSON de forma dinâmica? (ANGULAR 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Por exemplo ao iníciar quero que meu programa carregue todas as mensagens armazenadas anteriormente num arquivo JSON (mensagem.json)

```
ngOnInit() {
this.emissor = 'Victor';
this._http.get<PreparacaoDeMensagem[]>("../assets/db/mensagem.json")
  .subscribe(mensagem => {
    this.mensagem = mensagem
    //console.log('o valor é ', this.mensagem);
    this.adicionarMensagem(this.mensagem);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o `for`, desta forma você garante que todos os itens do seu arquivo serão lidos:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mensagem.length; i++) {
    this.adicionarMensagem(this.mensagem[i]);
}
```

o `.length` será o que vai fazer o `for` pegar todo o tamanho do seu arquivo e ler até o final.

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser algo diferente poderia utilizar o método do array .forEach

Ficaria algo assim

```
this.mensagem = mensagem
this.mensagem.forEach(men => {
  this.adicionarMensagem(men);
});
```

Esse método vai percorrer todo o array e executar o método para cada elemento do array.